# How to extract Text Content from a Web site using Beautiful using select() and specific CSS Selectors

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm learning to extract content from a Website using Python and BeautifulSoup.

This is the HTML structure:

```
<div id="preview-prediction" class="two-cols rc-b rc-r">
                    <span style="position: absolute; top: 0.5em; left: 1em; color: #808080;">Prediction: </span>
                    <div class="home">
                        <div class="team-name">
                            <img src="http://164.177.157.12/img/teams/13.png" class="team-emblem">
                            <a href="/Teams/13" class="team-link">Arsenal</a>
                        </div>
                        <span class="predicted-score">2</span>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="away">
                        <span class="predicted-score">1</span>
                        <div class="team-name">
                            <a href="/Teams/26" class="team-link">Liverpool</a>
                            <img src="http://164.177.157.12/img/teams/26.png" class="team-emblem">
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I want to extract the exact text from the specific tag in the page. I cannot use find_all() or find() as the page has this complex structure. So i'm using the select() function with the CSS selector:

```
 soup.select("#preview-prediction > .home > .team-name > .team-link")
```

The last class team-link contains the text which i need to extract. How to perform this task ?

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: Can you post the html that you're trying to manipulate?

Comment: Added the example HTML to the Question

Comment: Sorry !! I think i got it !! Never realised that the select returns the list of tags.

Just used: 

soup.select("#preview-prediction > .home > .team-name > .team-link")[0].string.

Do let me know if there is an efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would create a list of all the contents of selected tags.

```
>>> [i.text for i in soup.select('#preview-prediction > .home > .team-name > .team-link')]
['Arsenal']
```

**OR**

This would print the contents of first selected tag.

```
>>> soup.select('#preview-prediction > .home > .team-name > .team-link')[0].text
'Arsenal'
```

Comment: Thanks. I realized it a bit late. But really thanks.